# mapDispatchToProp not working as an object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

mapDispatchToProp not working when used as an object .But when I use it in classical way by returning dispatching explicitely, it is worling fine.
The code is as below

```
const incrementValue = () => ({
    type: 'INCREMENT',
});

const decrementValue = () => ({
    type: 'DECREMENT',
});

const reducer = (state = initState, action) => {

    if(action.type === 'INCREMENT') {
        return {
            count: state.count + 1,
        };
    }
    if(action.type === 'DECREMENT') {
        return {
            count: state.count - 1,
        };
    }

    return state;
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        const {count, increment, decrement} = this.props;
        console.log(count, increment, decrement);
        return(
            <div className="counter">
                <p>{count}</p>
                <div className="controls">
                    <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
                    <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state;
};

const mapDispatchToProp = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        increment() {
            dispatch(incrementValue());
        },
        
        decrement() {
            dispatch(decrementValue());
        }
    };
};

const dispatchActions = {
    incrementValue,
    decrementValue
}; // Not Working // mapDispatchToProps as an object

const CounterContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProp)(Counter);

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <CounterContainer />
</Provider>
, document.getElementById("root"));
```

When I use dispatchActions object in the second parameter instead of mapDispatchToProp it is not working as expected. What is wrong?
Edit: I have initialized count as follows

```
const initState = {
    count: 0,
};
```

Comment: i don' think this is the right approach

Comment: `dispatchActions` is not calling `dispatch`; it needs to call the `dispatch` function. `dispatchActions` is your action creators, and the actions they create need to be dispatched.

Comment: CHECK MY ANSWER YOUR CODE IS WORKING FINE YOU HAVE MISSED VARIABLE TO DECLARE

Comment: CHECK MY ANSWER UPDATED 3, now also your code working you have missed again mismatch naming. check below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated : 2**

**YOUR CODE CORRECT** Every thing correct in your code you have missed

you need to add below line **initState** in your code

```
let initState = {
  count: 0
}
const reducer = (state = initState, action) => {
```

check working link based one your code https://repl.it/@GopalaKrishnan3/Create-React-App

Demo Site URL https://create-react-app--gopalakrishnan3.repl.co/

[image]

**Updated 3**

Here also your code is working you have to changed actionCreater names properly while getting through this.props. like below,

```
    render() {
        const {count, incrementValue, decrementValue} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="counter">
                <p style={{"fontSize":"55px"}}>{count}</p>
                <div className="controls">
                    <button onClick={incrementValue}>Increment</button>
                    <button onClick={decrementValue}>Decrement</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state;
};

// const mapDispatchToProp = (dispatch) => {
//     return {
//         increment() { dispatch(incrementValue()); },
//         decrement() { dispatch(decrementValue()); }
//     };
// };

const dispatchActions = {
    incrementValue,  // you need change this name while getting props
    decrementValue   // you need change this name while getting props
};

const CounterContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchActions)(Counter);
```

[image: Check this new images]

Comment: check blogs if anyone wants to learn redux :  https://medium.com/@rgkrish183/esay-way-to-understand-react-apps-with-redux-concept-6d1a36d29c45

Comment: Working Copy Updated

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object. I am talking about this

Comment: updated : 3 have you checked my solution, if you got answer just comment me, i will also get some idea about your issue.

Answer (score -1):

What is the point of adding extra wrappers in mapDispatchToProp object ?

```
const mapDispatchToProp = () => {
  incrementValue,
  decrementValue
};
```

And call it in your components like `this.props.incrementValue`. Or you can map them however you want.

Comment: If you define `mapDispatch` as a function, [you are responsible for using `dispatch` yourself](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-a-function).  We recommend using the object form: `const mapDispatch = {incrementValue, decrementValue}`.

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object. I am talking about this